# UICollectionView cell change background while tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

Is there a possibility to change the background color of `UICollectionView` only while the element is tapped. I have tried:

```
-(void) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didHighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //change color when tapped
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didUnhighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //change back on touch up 
}
```

But the result is that I can see the change only when i keep my finger for a bit longer time. 
Is there some similar stuff like in `UITableViewCell` method `willSelectItemAtIndexPath:`?

Answer (score 29):

> But the result is that I can see the change only when i keep my finger for a bit longer time

The delay your are experiencing is probably related to the "Delay content touches" checkbox in the storyboard.

[image: the checkbox in storyboard]

Try to un-check it.

Answer (score 8):

I think you might want keep the selected cell with different background color, right?
Then try this code.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor magentaColor];
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor cyanColor];
}
```

Just simply assign different BG color for cells in different status. 
Additionally the code below is the documentation of sequence triggering methods while someone touches a collectionView cell. You can also find these documents in UICollectionView.h file, UICollectionViewDelegate protocol part.

```
// Methods for notification of selection/deselection and highlight/unhighlight events.
// The sequence of calls leading to selection from a user touch is:
//
// (when the touch begins)
// 1. -collectionView:shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPath:
// 2. -collectionView:didHighlightItemAtIndexPath:
//
// (when the touch lifts)
// 3. -collectionView:shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath: or -collectionView:shouldDeselectItemAtIndexPath:
// 4. -collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath: or -collectionView:didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:
// 5. -collectionView:didUnhighlightItemAtIndexPath:
```

[ios](/questions/tagged/ios) [uicollectionview](/questions/tagged/uicollectionview) [uicollectionviewdelegate](/questions/tagged/uicollectionviewdelegate)

Comment: I was looking for this answer... I was changing a custom grid to UICollectionView and TableView combination view. Implementing both methods allow for selecting and then changing the selection. Thanks Steve, this did the trick for me.

Answer (score 3):

```
// In Swift    
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell
  cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.magentaColor()
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell
  cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()
}
```

Comment: This method does not work when you scroll the collection view. Reused cells get colored too.

Comment: Should use `didHighlightItemAtIndexPath` and `didUnhighlightItemAtIndexPath` as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34503118/3681880) and the question above.