# Change Background of UICollectionView Cell on Tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewdelegate

I have a UICollectionView that I have created programmatically. I would like for the collection view to behave in the following way:

```
1. User touches cell
2. Cell background color changes
3. User releases touch
4. Cell background color changes
```

This should be a quick color change that happens just before the selector related to the tap action is executed in which the viewcontroller containing the collection view is popped off the stack.

I have been looking at this question: [UICollectionView cell change background while tap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17209863/uicollectionview-cell-change-background-while-tap)

in which there is the following summary of methods to use for this purpose:

```
// Methods for notification of selection/deselection and highlight/unhighlight events.
// The sequence of calls leading to selection from a user touch is:
//
// (when the touch begins)
// 1. -collectionView:shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPath:
// 2. -collectionView:didHighlightItemAtIndexPath:
//
// (when the touch lifts)
// 3. -collectionView:shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath: or -    collectionView:shouldDeselectItemAtIndexPath:
// 4. -collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath: or -collectionView:didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:
// 5. -collectionView:didUnhighlightItemAtIndexPath:
```

I am assuming I only need to implement one of the above methods from 'when touch begins' and 'when touch ends.' But no matter what I do, it appears that a background color changes and then remains changed. Here is an example of something I attempted which did not work:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
   //pop vc 
 }

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didHighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UICollectionViewCell* cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}
```

This results in the cell background color being changed only to red. I also looked at this question: [UICollectionView Select and Deselect issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330844/uicollectionview-select-and-deselect-issue) and tried implementing [UICollectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:] and calling it inside of didSelectItemAtIndexPath, but this did not work either. Collection view data source and delegate are set.

Comment: Check my answer here: <http://stackoverflow.com/a/44112257/5416775> It Works...!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The problem is that you are changing the color on *highlight* and changing it back on *deselect* instead that on *unhighlight*

You should simply change this:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}
```

to this:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didUnhighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}
```

Also, if you don't want to wait a bit before getting your highlight happen you should set the `delaysContentTouches` property of the collection view to `NO`

Edit: also ensure that you call

```
[collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
```

inside the -didSelectItemAtIndexPath method

Comment: delaysContentTouches <--- This!!! Needed my highlight to still work on a quick tap. Looked all over, can't believe it was one little property. Thanks!

Comment: `didUnhighlightItemAtIndexPath` doesn't seem to be working for me at all. What are the reasons it may not be firing?

Comment: have you set the UICollectionView's delegate?

Comment: I had issues with didUnhighlightItemAtIndexPath not getting called as well. Two things were causing the issue: 1. If you reload the table or the individual cell during didHighlight...() the highlight is lost and you won't get the unhighlight. 2. If you have another gesture recognizer attached to the collectionView the highlight will be lost once that kicks in (I had a LongPressGuestureRecognizer and the highlight was lost after about .5 sec).

Comment: `delaysContentTouches` was super helpful, thanks @AntonioE. @bmjohns

Answer (score 34):

**Swift 3 version**

Add the following two methods to your view controller class:

```
// change background color when user touches cell
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}

// change background color back when user releases touch
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didUnhighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
}
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31735229/3681880) for help in setting up a basic collection view in Swift.

Answer (score 6):

**Edit: Answer in Swift 3**

```
var selectedIndex = Int ()

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    cell.backgroundColor = selectedIndex == indexPath.row ? UIColor.green : UIColor.red

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    selectedIndex = indexPath.row

    self.yourCollctionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: why would you reload the whole collectionview just to change the color of a single cell?

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution. And I'm sure it really works.
I provide three methods to highlight a cell (selectedBackgroundView, tint `cell.contentView` and tint a special area).

How to use:
1. just inherit `BaseCollectionViewCell` and do nothing;
2. inherit and set `specialHighlightedArea = UIView()`, and `contentView.addSubView(specialHighlightedArea)`, then layout it or add constraint to use Auto Layout;
3. if you don't need highlight effect, just write a method named 'shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPath' defined by `UICollectionViewDelegate` and make it return false, or set `cell.shouldTintBackgroundWhenSelected = false` and set `specialHighlightedArea = nil` and remove it from superView.

```
/// same with UITableViewCell's selected backgroundColor
private let highlightedColor = UIColor(rgb: 0xD8D8D8) 

/// you can make all your collectionViewCell inherit BaseCollectionViewCell
class BaseCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    /// change it as you wish when or after initializing
    var shouldTintBackgroundWhenSelected = true

    /// you can give a special view when selected
    var specialHighlightedArea: UIView? 

    // make lightgray background display immediately(使灰背景立即出现)
    override var isHighlighted: Bool { 
        willSet {
            onSelected(newValue)
        }
    }

    // keep lightGray background until unselected (保留灰背景)
    override var isSelected: Bool { 
        willSet {
            onSelected(newValue)
        }
    }

    func onSelected(_ newValue: Bool) {
        guard selectedBackgroundView == nil else { return }
        if shouldTintBackgroundWhenSelected {
            contentView.backgroundColor = newValue ? highlightedColor : UIColor.clear
        }
        if let area = specialHighlightedArea {
            area.backgroundColor = newValue ? UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.4) : UIColor.clear
        }
    }
}

extension UIColor {
    convenience init(rgb: Int, alpha: CGFloat = 1.0) {
        self.init(red: CGFloat((rgb & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0, green: CGFloat((rgb & 0xFF00) >> 8) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(rgb & 0xFF) / 255.0, alpha: alpha)
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't the `specialHighlightedArea` actually be weak?

Comment: @SamerMurad When using xib/storyboard, you can use `weak`.

Comment: Really? I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with the xib/storyboard. I mean the UI already holds the UIView, so there is no actual need for the strong reference, is there?

Answer (score 2):

Simple binary logic solution. Works with Swift 3 and 4:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt
    indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CategoryCell
    let lastCellColor = cell.backgroundColor
    if cell.isSelected {cell.backgroundColor = .green} else {cell.backgroundColor = lastCellColor}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add all the subviews inside `contentView`,
use `backgroundView` and `selectedBackgroundView` from `UICollectionViewCell`. Do not set `contentView.backgroundColor`.

```
// Add this inside your cell configuration.
private func setupSelectionColor() {
    let backgroundView = UIView()
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = .white
    self.backgroundView = backgroundView

    let selectedBackgroundView = UIView()
    selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = .orange
    self.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBackgroundView
}

// Add the deselection inside didSelectCallback
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```