# CollectionView, change Cell color

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

i have collectionView with 52 images in it,

on `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method i have this code:

```
var cell : UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)! 
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
```

background color is changing, BUT, when i scroll down my collectionView, another cell there have green background color,
I assume `collectionView` doing some redrawing and some strange things happen with indexPath or something,

Could really use advice on how to change color of just one cell, even when you scroll collection view up and down,

Thanks!

D

Comment: did you build the collectionView using `InterfaceBuilder` ?

Comment: its populated with images programmatically, but created in storyboard.

Comment: Okay then you can change the cell's background color from the cell's properties in the storyboard, no need to code. Do you know how to do that ?

Comment: i need to change color when person select one =)

Comment: Check My answer here: <http://stackoverflow.com/a/44112257/5416775> It may works...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cell is getting reused. That's the reason. 
In your cell class you should add the default background in the prepareForReuse method. 
Or you can set background in your cellforItemAtIndexPath. The first approach is better.

Comment: thanks, it solved the problem partially ^_^, now when I scroll up or down, my selected cell loosing green color. But there are no duplicates hehe.

Comment: also, cellforItemAtIndexPath method, makes 2 green cells as well.

Comment: You can store the selectedIndex in a property and check if it's selected make it green in cellforItemAtIndexPath.

Comment: Which one you're trying , prepareForReuse or cellForItemAtIndexPath?

Comment: Make sure always set a background color if it's selected or not. It's good to understand how cell reuse works in collection view that's what you're dealing with.

Comment: yeah, thanks, i set background color to clear for prepareForReuse. but my original selected cell also loosing color. I try to dig more.

Comment: You should know the order these things get called. The cell object you get in cellforItemAtIndexPath is the reused cell and come after your prepareForReuse did the work, you should do other stuff like coloring the selected cell after that.

Answer (score 2):

thanks to MKoosej and other guys,

I managed to get it work,

had to add method to my customCell.swift:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }
```

then in cellForItemAtIndexPath, i check stored indexPath.row, if its was selected then i changed color.

Now it works when you scroll.

Thanks again, learned something new!

Deniss

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

In your CustomCell.m file:

```
-(void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted
{
if (highlighted)
{
    self.layer.opacity = 0.6;
    //or whatever you want here
}
else{
    self.layer.opacity = 1.0;
    //revert back the changes 
}
}
```

And you're good to go.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: its a CollectionView not tableView =)

Comment: then use it in the collectionView method, i haven't used collectionView before, but the code is correct, test it :)

Comment: Do you use a custom class  ?

Comment: custom class for cell, yes. I need them to be different background colors as well.

Comment: i'm using swift, so I end up with similar code that you offered, but same thing happens, when you scroll, cell being reused and opacity goes back to 1.0 here:  var Hihglighted:Bool = false {
        didSet{
            self.layer.opacity = 0.6;
            }
    }

Comment: if i leave prepareForReuse method, then i have 2 cells with opacity changed.

Comment: hmmm weird, this is the official documentation

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionReusableView_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionReusableView/prepareForReuse