# how to change backgroundColor of a cell even it reloads in collectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

currently i am working on a app using collectionview now facing few issue with.

> i'm searching a way to give the user to change it's collectionView cells backgroundColor but this app always reload it in viewDidAppear so even i change the cell's background color it becomes all white again.

do you have any good ideas for this? 
like saving the indexPath of the cell and the backgroundColor

Thanks in advance.

Comment: apply the following ans of this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674317/changing-cell-background-color-in-uicollectionview-in-swift)..

Comment: Yeap, your idea sounds good, using a `[NSIndexPath:UIColor]` dictionary should do the trick

Comment: Have you try like Cristik suggested, or you getting any idea about that?