# How to set background color in cell section not header section?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicolor

I created a collectionView and want to set the cell section background color

since I do not know how many rows it have and I do not want to set background color in other sections

set the whole cell section backgroundcolor

Comment: I do believe you'll have to set background color in the cellForRowAt method for each cell separately, you'll check if indexPath.section == something then set the corresponding color.

Comment: https://github.com/devxoul/UICollectionViewFlexLayout

Comment: iOS 13+ -> UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout

Comment: What do you have in `collectionViewCell` ??? , as if that element covers all area then `cell.backgroundColor` will not appear.....otherwise answer of @Aaira Samson should work....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34697261/7316675 this might help you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing cell background color in UICollectionView in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674317/changing-cell-background-color-in-uicollectionview-in-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I find the solution.

In the cell there is two UIView that is cell View and contentView. And all views you add is in the contentView. So I should:

- set the cell background color
- add a layer which frame is inseted by the cell frame
- set the layer background color
- add views

Answer (score 1):

You can do it on your cellForItemAt, hope this helps :)

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! SampleCell
    if indexPath.section == 1 {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemPink
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with following code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! TestCell

        if indexPath.section == 1 {

           cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        } else {

           cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange

        }

        return cell

     }
```