# How to change the color of View in collection view

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

How to change the color of view in collection view when it select and when the select the other view before view came to original color How to set it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674317/changing-cell-background-color-in-uicollectionview-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [didSelectItemAtIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618032-collectionview) method and the [didDeselectItemAtIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618035-collectionview) method from the [UICollectionViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate) protocol. `UICollectionViewDelegate` is an Objective-C protocol, indicated by `@objc`, that allows you to have optional methods like `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` and `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath` that you can choose to implement optionally in your delegate.

When `UICollectionView` gets instantiated initially, it goes through all the available methods you've implemented in the instance of `UICollectionViewDelegate` with [responds(to:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobjectprotocol/1418583-responds), which takes a selector parameter and returns a bool, to see which methods from the `UICollectionViewDelegate` protocol you've implemented without actually sending a message to them. As it detects the following methods, it remembers them and calls those methods whenever you select or deselect a cell from the collection view:

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    if let indexPaths = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems, let firstIndex = indexPaths.first {
        cell.backgroundColor = firstIndex == indexPath ? .white : .gray
    }
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) {
        cell.backgroundColor = .white
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) else {
        return
    }
    cell.backgroundColor = .gray
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the [collectionView(_:didHighlightItemAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618049-collectionview) method and the [collectionView(_:didUnhighlightItemAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618027-collectionview%60%20method) method.  The following sample code is from [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/changing_the_appearance_of_selected_and_highlighted_cells):

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.4932718873, blue: 0.4739984274, alpha: 1)
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didUnhighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add two methods for changing colour of the view or cell in the collectionView:-

//When cell got selected

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath){
        cell.backgroundColor = .green
    }
}
```

//When cell deselected

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath){
        cell.backgroundColor = .clear
    }
}
```

If you have view inside your cell as backgroundView then you can use same functions and just need to replace cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor in place of the cell.backgroundColor. Just remember "backgroundView" is the name of the view you have inside cell.

If you want more information about this then you can follow below attached links:-

1). https://www.tutorialfor.com/questions-296884.html

2). https://en.it1352.com/article/fccf358a040b4ddba872d7324602754c.html