# How to reduce the amount of time between a tap on a cell and the running of certain code?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, cell, tap

I have the below code which successfully causes a cell in a `collectionView` to depress when tapped.

The issue is that one must hold for pretty long before the depression happens. Don't get me wrong. It's only about 1 second, but if you were to compare that speed to the speed of snapchat you can clearly see snapchat's is almost instant.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

     UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {

         collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)!.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: 0.95, y: 0.95)

      })
 }
```

**Question:** How could I make this animation for each cell, be instant or closer to it, like snapchat?

### Update:

This seems to be doing it:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {

        collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)!.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: 0.95, y: 0.95)

    }) { (true) in

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {

            collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)!.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: 1, y: 1)

        })

    }

}
```

This is an option if anyone wants something basic.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618032-collectionview?language=objc

Comment: @canister_exister, no, that runs after having let go. The method above runs when the user is holding down, because that is when this needs to start.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922613/4311935

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29242979/4311935

Comment: what is the reason to use didHighlightItemAt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disable the `collectionView` content touch delay in interface builder:

[image: Delay]

or in code:

```
myCollectionView.delaysContentTouches = false
```

**Tip**: enabling `.beginFromCurrentState` option for this animation will cause it looks more fluid and responsive. From Apple's docs on `beginFromCurrentState`:

> Start the animation from the current setting associated with an already in-flight animation.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0, options: [.beginFromCurrentState], animations: { 
}) { finished in 
}
```

Comment: would this be the correct implementation of your tip?: myCollectionView. beginFromCurrentState = true //because it says there is no .beginFromCurrentState

Comment: No, its for `UIView.animate` function

Answer (score 0):

If you want instantness you can transform to and back in touchesBegan and touchesEnded/touchesCanceled methods of your custom UICollectionViewCell